# iOS 6 - Can't gain access to photos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html

In there it says "For the photo library, the existing interface supports the app being denied access." Does it mean that there is no way for the app to ask the user permission to access his photos? He'll need to manualy go to settings -> privacy -> Photos and toggle my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ALAssets` to get access to photo library, for the first time system will ask user if he want's to share photos to your app. If user taps "Allow" - everything will be ok, otherwise, user should go to the preferences and allow it manually when he wants.
Hope it helped

Comment: ALAssets? I'm using UIImagePickerController to access the camera roll

Comment: I forgot, there is no matter what class you are using. UIImagePickerController will also ask user if he wants to share photos. This message appears only at first time access his photos. Event if user will select "Deny" - message won't appear any more. User should go to settings and allow it by himself.

Answer (score 0):

No, that not true. iOS will ask user for persmission when he first time accesses his photos from your app.